# Asymptotic growth of antichains in divisibility posets

Tags: co.combinatorics, asymptotics, posets

The following question is inspired by a problem that Erdős used to ask epsilons. It asks to prove that if one chooses a subset of $\lbrace 1,\dots,n\rbrace$ with more than $\lfloor\frac{n+1}{2}\rfloor$ elements, then there are two numbers in this subset with an integer ratio.

My question is about subsets which don't satisfy that conclusion, i.e. no element divides the other. So to phrase it more succinctly, how many antichains are there in the divisibility poset $\mathcal P_n$? The partial order here is $x\le y$ if $x|y$. Let's denote this number by $p_n$.

Of course an exact enumeration is not possible in such cases, so one looks for asymptotics. I haven't been able to do much progress at that, either.

What I have so far is really just the obvious bounds one gets from the solution of the problem mentioned in the beginning of this post. For the lower bound, by looking at numbers $> \frac{n}{2}$ one obtains $p_n\geq 2^{\frac{n}{2}}$.

For the upper bound, by using the fact that we have chains $\lbrace k,2k,4k\dots\rbrace$ for every odd $k$, one obtains $p_n\le 2^{cn}$ where
$$c=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{\log_2 n}{2^n}\approx 0.73264948$$
Can somebody help me bridge the gap between these two bounds?

Comment: Let $A_n$ be the roughly $n/6$ integers in $(n/3,n/2)$. Let $B_n$ be the integers in $(n/2 + 1,n]$ that are of the form $2m$, $m \in A_n$. Let $C_n$ be the integers in $(n/2+1,n]$. By considering $C_n \setminus B_n$ we get $2^{n/2-n/6}$. By considering $A_n$ and $B_n$ we get $3^{n/6}$. So a lower bound is $2^{(0.5+r/6)n}$ where $2^r=1.5$.

Comment: Perhaps you can run a computer experiment for small $n$, say, $n\le 20$. Also I guess one needs only to know the maximal antichains, and the semilattice (under intersection) they generate. I wonder, what this semilattice is for small $n$. It must be something quite "regular". The whole problem, in my opinion, should have a definite answer, that is the limit of $(\log p_n)/n$ should exist and be something nice. 

Comment: @Mark: No need to run computer experiments, Sloane's A051026 (http://oeis.org/A051026) has the first few terms. 

Comment: @Guntram: Thanks! I did feel that it is too natural a question to appear now for the first time. 

Comment: @Guntram: Thanks! Now I feel silly, because I couldn't find this sequence in OEIS as I wasn't counting the empty set. "Primitive sequnces" does give a lot of hits on google, including some articles of Erdos. It will take a while to go through those and check what the answer to this question is.

Comment: Hmm, most papers I found concern with finding density bounds or similar things on primitive sequences. I wonder if these can be translated in bounds for the number of such sequences...

Comment: @GjergjiZaimi: Interesting question. I have asked a related question in http://mathoverflow.net/questions/224637/weighted-maximal-number-of-disjoint-chains-in-the-integer-divisibility-poset-for

Comment: I've obtained some numbers beyond the ones provided on OEIS (for $n \sim 100$), and the optimal value of $c$ seems to be around 0.64. Still have no clue what an analytic answer could be.

Comment: @MikhailTikhomirov Tried to write down an expression based on your nice answer to the other question!

Answer (score 1):

Here is an expression for $c$ based on Mikhail Tikhomirov's nice answer to the question ([divisibility independence](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/280985/divisibility-independence)). Let us also use his notation from that answer. With $1\leq x \leq n$, $x\equiv 1 \bmod 2$, define $d(x)$ in the same way except that the antichain does not need to be an $S_m(n)$. We think of $d(x)$ as being in $E(x)=\{\alpha,0,1,\dots,\lfloor\log(n/x)/\log 2 \rfloor\}$ where $\alpha$ is a symbol such that if $d(x)\not=\alpha$ then $d(x)$ has the same meaning in that answer, and if $d(x)=\alpha$, it means that no number of the form $x2^e$ is in the antichain. (Also, since the antichain need not be maximal, we clearly may have $d(x)<\left\lfloor\frac{\log\lfloor n/x \rfloor}{\log 3}\right\rfloor$ if $d(x)\not=\alpha$ in this case.)
Let $P(x,y)$ be the statement $x|y \Rightarrow (d(x)\not=\alpha \Rightarrow (d(y)=\alpha \mbox{ or }d(y)<d(x)))$. Then
$$
2^{cn}=\sum_{\substack{(d(1),d(3),\dots,d(2\lfloor(n+1)/2\rfloor-1))\in \prod_{x\in \{1,3,\dots,2\lfloor(n+1)/2\rfloor-1\}}E(x)\\P(x,y) \forall (x,y)\in\{1,3,\dots,2\lfloor(n+1)/2\rfloor-1\}^2}}1
$$
Well, the main thing is to study that condition on the sum.

Comment: I've been thinking about how to give estimates on this sum for some time, but couldn't break the existing (kinda trivial) bounds yet.

Comment: @MikhailTikhomirov It is an interesting question. Thanks for your insight.