# More on divisibility

Tags: nt.number-theory, mg.metric-geometry

This is a fuzzier follow-up to [this question.](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/280985/divisibility-independence) Again, we construct the graph whose vertices are integers from $1$ to $n,$ and two vertices are connected whenever one of the corresponding integers divides the other, and then we lay the graph out radially, so the vertex corresponding to $1$ is at the center of the circle, and the others are clockwise around the circumference This is what we get (for $n=180$). There are obviously patterns, but how do we explain them?

[image: divisibility graph for $n=180$]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

These curves are arcs of epicycloids. In particular, the one tangent to the vertical line is half of the [cardioid](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cardioid). If, for a positive integer $k$, you draw a line from $\alpha$ to $k\alpha$ modulo $2\pi$ for all $\alpha$, the envelope will be the complete epicycloid. (For $k$ negative, you get hypocycloids.)

This observation is due to Luigi Cremona.

Comment: What's the reference for the Cremona attribution?

Comment: Unfortunately I don't have a reference. I found the attribution on websites.